# macchanger on xubuntu 16.04 broken. Fix?

Tags: networking, xubuntu

Since the upgrade to 16.04 this command:

```
sudo service network-manager stop && sudo macchanger -r wlan0 && sudo service network-manager start
```

returns:

```
[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Device or resource busy
```

It should change the MAC, given that I sudoed, but no.

I also tried:

```
sudo ip link set wlan0 down && sudo ip link set dev wlan0 address 46:74:26:d5:17:04 && sudo ip link set wlan0 up
```

In this case, MAC was changed, the IP did not ( I always got new IP's when changing MAC) and no connection was reached

A third try:

```
sudo ip link set wlan0 down && sudo macchanger -r wlan0 && sudo ip link set wlan0 up
```

MAC did change, IP did not, and no connection was reached.

What do I have to do to get macchanger to work again?

Comment: https://github.com/jerabaul29/randommac seems promising. I am working on trying it out now.

Answer (score 0):

The first set of commands are close. The error you are seeing is because your wlan0 is still up.

```
sudo service network-manager stop && sudo ifconfig wlan0 down && sudo macchanger -a wlan0 && sudo ifconfig wlan0 up && sudo service network-manager start
```

In a perfect world this should work as expected but network-manager resets the mac on startup in 16.04. It seems as though this is an issue with network-manager and it appears that they are aware.
[bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1573856)